# Nodejs showing Bandwidth Limit Exceeded

Tags: node.js, express

For some strange reason i am getting Bandwidth Limit Exceeded for just these lines of code in nodejs / express

```
app.use('/add',function(req,res){
var a=req.query.a;
var b=req.query.b;
res.send((a-0)+(b-0));
```

**res.send((a)+(b));** works fine but **res.send((a-0)+(b-0))** gives error.
Is this nodejs problem or express issue ?

Comment: What are the values of `a` and `b` and what does any of the code you posted have to do with the error message and what's the point of your code?

Comment: @jfriend00 strangely this is the error that is coming with the code and the url used is http://localhost/add?a=5&b=504 . The point of code is just to show addition using node. I was using a+b simply but it was getting concatenated so i tried using (a-0)+(b-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Express source code if you pass a number to `res.send()` it will turn it into `res.status()` and then look up a string for that particular status code and send that as the actual response.

And, low and behold:

```
HTTP Status Code 509 - Bandwidth Limit Exceeded
```

So, that explains what is going on.

---

If you intend to send just the 509, then turn it into a string before sending it.